# Wordpress display taxonomy as drop down menu

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I've built a hierarchical taxonomy that displays a master list of available fragrances in the admin. When you create a page, you checkmark the fragrances that are available for that particular page. I used this code to functions.php and it seems to work in the admin:

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

function build_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy(
'scents',
'page',
array( 'hierarchical' => true,
'label' => 'Scents',
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => true ) );
}
```

Now I need to output the checkmarked items so they display on the page in the form of a drop down menu.

The problem is that it outputs ALL scents that have been check marked across ALL pages. I just need it to output the ones that have been check marked on the page you're on.

Here's the code I used:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=scents'); ?>
```

How do I edit this so that it only shows the fragrances for the page I'm on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like `wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'scents')`

Chek out the docs at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example, please? I looked at the documentation but it didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: for instance: 

    function get_marked_scents( $postid = null ){
     if ( is_null($postid) ) {
      // if no $postid was defined, let's use the global $post->ID
      global $post;
      $postid = $post->ID;
     }
     // 'scents' is the taxonomy slug
     $scents = wp_get_object_terms($postid, 'scents');
     if ( !is_wp_error($scents) && !empty($scents) ) {
      foreach ( $scents as $scent ) {
       // build dropdown here
      }
     }
    }

... sorry I took so long